# org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: URL 'svn+ssh://myserver/mypath/myproject/trunk/.project' non-existent in that revision

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, svnkit

I have an issue with Subversive on Eclipse.

These are the versions:

```
ECLIPSE
Version: Neon.1 Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20160913-0900

SUBVERSIVE
4.0.3.I20161129-1700

SVN CONNECTOR:
SVNKit 1.8.14 r10627 (SVN 1.9.0 compatible, all platforms)
```

I am on a branch of a project "myproject", the branch is "branch01".
The project is versioned on a SVN server 1.9.

I want to create another branch starting from "branch01", so I make the following:

1. Right-click on the project in Project Explorer
2. I select Team -> Branch...
3. Then, in the new Branch Dialog, I set the name and the flag "Start working in the new Branch"
4. Clik on OK

This is the error I obtain:

```
SVN: '0x0040011a: Call Menu Action' operation finished with error: Can't overwrite cause with org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: URL 'svn+ssh://myserver/mypath/myproject/trunk/.project' non-existent in that revision
Can't overwrite cause with org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: URL 'svn+ssh://myserver/mypath/myproject/trunk/.project' non-existent in that revision
```

I don't understand why the plugin is looking for "/trunk/.project".
I'm not on the trunk, I'm on a branch "branch01" and I want to create a second branch from it.

How to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error at checking out a project. This worked for me:

- Open Window>Preferences
- Select Team>SVN in the navigation tree.
- Select the Project stucture tab.
- Switch off the "Use'.project' project name for the working copy
  instead of repository folder name"  checkbox.